# How to bloat pg_wal?

Tags: postgresql

For some training purposes, I'd like to reproduce a bloated pg_wal directory so that I can show an example of what happens when `Postgres` shuts down because of insufficient disk space.

So far I've tried feeding `psql` the ouptut of the following bash script :

```sh
#!/bin/sh
        
for i in {1..100}; do
   echo "create table temp_$i (id text);" >> bloat_wals.sql
   for j in {1..1000}; do
      echo "insert into temp_$i values('`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alpha:]' | fold -w ${1:-20} | head -n 1`');" >> bloat_wals.sql
   done
   echo "drop table temp_$i;" >> bloat_wals.sql
done
```

which generates the following sql file `bloat_wals.sql` :

```
create table temp_1 (id text);
insert into temp_1 values('KRzMmncvZzjZlbLTNtQd');
insert into temp_1 values('haXsbsFOUfavkUNeLTSP');
insert into temp_1 values('LYVhfMlWRnfVnhPIvYtb');
...
drop table temp_1;
create table temp_2 (id text);
insert into temp_2 values('qKqRjlCqUddycHENZrQJ');
insert into temp_2 values('SeztNglqJQfWICoyZeCs');
insert into temp_2 values('cgKVcTteWGZXWEHrqTqa');
drop table temp_2;
create table temp_3 (id text);
insert into temp_3 values('OPuidYENyZWfIlsehSvS');
insert into temp_3 values('ZYakjYKzkbwAkjBksKBi');
insert into temp_3 values('oUUBHKMZQeMQejJyvaZL');
...
insert into temp_100 values('SeztNglqJQfWICoyZeCs');
insert into temp_100 values('cgKVcTteWGZXWEHrqTqa');
drop table temp_100;
```

But this is not increasing the size of the `pg_wal` directory significantly.

From reading about Postgres wal configuration documentation, it looks like the following parameters/functions could be used to achieve this :

```
 - checkpoint_timeout
 - max_wal_size
 - pg_switch_wal ()
 - archive_command=/bin/true
```

Please let me know what would be the easiest way to bloat a pg_wal directory ? I'm using a raw database so any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to configure WAL archiving in a way that is bound to fail:

```
archive_mode = on
archive_command = '/bin/false'
```

Then restart PostgreSQL and generate WAL.

Instead of generating a lot of WAL, you could also call the `pg_switch_wal()` function, which will switch to the next WAL segments (so it acts as if 16MB worth of WAL had been written).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the case I presented, `pg_wal` directory was still not really increasing in size, but by using `psql -c "select pg_switch_wal ();"` along with your recommendation is very rapidly increased disk space consumption.

Comment: That's an option. Otherwise you have to generate WAL, like I wrote, by running enough `INSERT` statements.